# How to make a <img> tile vertically?

Tags: html, image, background, html4

I need to make a background for a website cover the entire screen, BUT tile vertically. I cant use HTML5. [Here is the website,](http://pmsbpadover.webs.com/index.htm) sorry the code is messy I wrote the original code a few years back when I didnt know how to right organized code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the problem with using CSS background-image with the repeat-y option is that the image won't fill the width of the screen.

To get the image to fill the width and ALSO tile vertically do the following.
I've tested and it works.

1. Remove the current `<div class="background">` block containing your background images
2. Add the following code block to the `<center>` element you have on your page

   > ```
   > <center style="">
   >     <div class="background">
   >         <img src="BG/b1.jpg" />
   >         <img src="BG/b1.jpg" />
   >         <img src="BG/b1.jpg" />
   >     </div>
   >
   >     ...rest of code
   > ```
3. now add/modify the following CSS statements

> ```
> center
> {
>   position:relative;
> }
> .background 
> {
>   height:100%;
>   width:100%;
>   min-height:800px;
>   min-width:760px;
>   position:absolute;
>   overflow:hidden;
>   left:0px;
>   top:0px;
>   z-index:-1;
> }
> .background img
> {
>   display:block;
>   height:auto;
>   width:100%;
>   min-height: 800px;
>   min-width:760px;
> }
> ```

Comment: working example here of your modified page
http://www.digitalbiscuits.co.uk/testbed/answer.htm

Works in IE7+, Chrome and Firefox 10

Comment: thanks works perfectly, although i was trying to stay away from having a bunch of <img> tags just for the background, but I guess this is the only way without HTML5

Comment: @EfeOzturkoglu, my answer doesn't require HTML5. Only requires `background-size`, which is supported in Firefox 4+ (3.6 if you include `-moz-background-size`), Safari 4.1+ (3.0 if you include `-webkit-background-size`), Chrome, Opera 10+, and Internet Explorer 9+. Sadly, it does not work in IE8 and below, but depending on your situation, you can simply provide them with a fallback (non-resized background).

Comment: @bfrohs - Your answer is really elegant and simple, but unfortunately IE8 is still generally the most used browser, and will be for a long time.
For one website I've done SEO for, 13,000 of the 22.5K visitors for the last year were using a version of IE.
Of that figure 11.5K were using IE8 or lower. 
You can't afford to design your website just for people using modern browsers.

Comment: @DigitalBiscuits, it all depends on the website you're developing for. For example, for my company's website, less than 25% of users are using IE (with a much smaller portion being <IE8). And websites do not have to look exactly the same in all browsers. For example, having a background image that doesn't repeat, or a solid background (preferably) is oftentimes an acceptable way to serve pages to older browsers, especially when you're attempting to use features like this. But, again, this all depends on the percent of users using the browsers you're targeting.

Comment: @bfrohs - You're right, it does depend on the intended audience and circumstances. Personally I wouldn't use the percentage of users' browsers as an indicator of whether I should or shouldn't bother with cross browser compatibility, especially when it comes to public facing projects for clients. The most important thing though is to make sure you maintain usability across platforms and browsers. If a background image doesn't repeat for a user using IE that's not such a big issue. However if text disappears or a button doesn't work, then you have an issue...even if it's only x amount of users.

Answer (score 0):

In your CSS use background-repeat:repeat-y to repeat vertically.  Use background-repeat:repeat to repeat vertically and horizonally.

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_background-repeat.asp

CSS

```
body
{
    background-image:url('paper.gif');
    background-repeat:repeat-y;
}
```

Comment: you dont understand, i have to make it stretch to fill the page horizontally, AND repeat vertically

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution that I believe is what you're looking for. You can also use a length (e.g., `50px`) instead of `auto` for the height.

```
#background {
 background-image:url("image.png");
 background-size:100% auto;
 background-repeat:repeat-y;
}
```

### Working Example

- [Horizontal Stretch + Vertical Repeat Base64 Background](http://jsfiddle.net/aWqMk/) (tested in Firefox 11 and Chrome)

### Browser Support

- Firefox 4+ (3.6 if you include `-moz-background-size`)
- Safari 4.1+ (3.0 if you include `-webkit-background-size`)
- Chrome
- Opera 10+ (9.5 if you include `-o-background-size`)
- Internet Explorer 9+ (non-resized background for IE8 and lower)

Comment: Great answer, voted up.
If you introduce an IE Javascript fallback, maybe using modernizer to detect IE8 or lower, then this answer would be perfect.